# How to compress a serialized List<> efficiently in C#

Tags: c#, list, serialization, compression

To make a long program simplified, I'm using a Map class which contains a List (aka tilemap). In the current scenario, my map must have a dimension of 2048x2048 pixels, divided into 16x16 (pixels) cells, including 8 layers. That's a total of (128x128 cells) times 8 = 131072 Tile elements.

My biggest issue is when I'm serializing the Map object and I'm trying to compress it with gzip. However the output file is 400 KB (or 640 KB without gzip), which I think is faily big. I hoped it to be less than 40 KB, especially I used only Tile reference in the whole tilemap here. The file is almost as large as if I used a big 2048x2048 for my entire scene while the purpose of using tiles is to make it very small in size.

Is there something I'm completely misunderstanding? Is there a very efficient way to compress a List<>?

Below you'll find code snippets. I tried to stay ultra simple in those examples, it's fairly more complex in my real program.

Here's the Map class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Map
{
    public List<Tile> tilemap = new List<Tile>();

    public Map()
    {
        Tile single_tile = new Tile();

        // Fill entire tilemap with one single tile object
        for(int i = 0; i < 131072; i++)
        {
            tilemap.Add( single_tile );
        }

    }

    public Map(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        tilemap = (List<Tile>)info.GetValue("tilemap", typeof(List<Tile>));
    }

    public void  GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("tilemap", tilemap);
    }

}
```

Here's the Tile class.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Tile
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int type;
    public int passage;
    public bool autotiled;

    public Tile()
    {

    }

    public Tile(int _id)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = "Grass";
        type = 1;
        passage = 2;
        autotiled = false;
    }

    public Tile(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        id = (int)info.GetValue("id", typeof(int));
        name = (string)info.GetValue("name", typeof(string));
        type = (int)info.GetValue("type", typeof(int));
        passage = (int)info.GetValue("passage", typeof(int));
        autotiled = (bool)info.GetValue("autotiled", typeof(bool));
    }

    public void  GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("id", id);
        info.AddValue("name", name);
        info.AddValue("type", type);
        info.AddValue("passage", passage);
        info.AddValue("autotiled", autotiled);
    }

}
```

And finally here's the Serialization + Compression process

```
Map map = new Map();
string filename = "Game_Data\\" + "Map_1.txt";

Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);

GZipStream compressor = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress );

BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bFormatter.Serialize(compressor, obj);
compressor.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Can the same tile occur repeatedly in the same tilemap list?

Comment: what exactly is your concern with size?

Comment: My concern is I don't want my entire project + saved objects end up being 2 gig when it can be kept below 100 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the same tiles can occur repeatedly in the same map, you could split the information into a list of unique tiles and a list describing the position of the tiles in the map.

```
IEnumerable<Tile> uniqueTiles = tilemap.Distinct();
// Serialize these tiles, i.e each unique tile only once.

IEnumerable<int> map = tilemap.Select(m => m.id);
// Serialize the IDs.
```

When deserializing the tiles, first load the tiles into a dictionary using the ID as key.

```
var tileDict = new Dictionary<int, Tile>();
```

Using the list of IDs and this dictionary, you can now quickly reconstruct the original tilemap.

```
List<int> ids = ... // Deserialized IDs.
var tilemap = new List<Tile>(ids.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++) {
    tilemap.Add(tileDict[ids[i]];
}
```

Comment: I dont think he is referring to pixels. I think this is metadata for what will be displayed.

Comment: @kmacdonald: I changed my answer completely. Thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not trying to compress at the n mimage level, but at the metadata level to be reused a tile editor. I'll make a few tests with your examples but I'm afraid to end up with bigger lists/arrays.

Answer (score 1):

131072 elements at 4byte per element (one reference) makes 512kb of raw data, so you get exactly what you should get. The rest of the data should be overhead from the serialisation.

The only way I see to improve that, would be not to save every tile, but only important ones/not default ones, the same a sparse matrix works. Depending on you map, there may be even whole layers you do not have to actually save.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a compact representation, don't use `BinaryFormatter`. `BinaryFormatter` implements a format that is a big trade-off of many things.

I understand this is image data. So save it as a 2048x2048 PNG image and use ScriptPNG to minify it.

If it is not an image, implement a custom binary serialization format.